# MIP: Adding a Variable to Indicate Equality

Tags: python, or-tools, mixed-integer-programming

I am trying to build a MIP model in the OR Tools Python API. I have two expressions `x` and `y` and want to make a variable `b` that is equal to 1 when `x == y` and 0 otherwise. What I've tried doing so far is adding the constraint that `-M(1 - b) <= x - y <= M(1 - b)` for some big value of `M`, which forces `b` to be 0 if `x != y`. Where I am stuck is adding a constraint that forces `b` to be 1 if `x == y`. I think I would want something such as `x - y >= 1 - b` or `y - x >= 1 - b`, but I don't know how to logically combine constraints like this. Any suggestions on how to do this? Or for some totally different approach?

Comment: Important to know about the bools: `False == 0 && True == 1`

Comment: Do you mean that I should just say `b = x == y`? I don't think I am able to add a constraint in that form to the model.

Comment: I mean that the boolean value True is literally equal to the number 1 and the boolean value False is literally equal to the number 0.

Answer (score 0):

I think the following expressions would work for you:

```
b <= x - y + 1
b <= y - x + 1
b >= 1-x + 1-y - 1
b >= y + x - 1
```

Comment: Sorry, I should have mentioned that `x` and `y` are integer variables and not necessarily binary, and I think this only works when they are binary.

Answer (score 0):

Please note that depending on the nature of the model, the CP-SAT solver could prove competitive. And it provides reification and half-reification natively.

Please have a look at

- [**Specific answer**] https://github.com/google/or-tools/blob/master/ortools/sat/doc/channeling.md
- [**Introduction**] https://developers.google.com/optimization/cp/cp_solver#cp-sat_example
- [**CP-SAT recipes**] https://github.com/google/or-tools/blob/master/ortools/sat/doc/index.md

Comment: The reason I am using OR-tools is to be able to plug my model into lots of different solvers in order to compare them. Does CP-SAT also support this?

Comment: no, CP-SAT is a stand alone solver. There is a backend for minizinc though.